# Как правильно вывести массив по столбцам?

Tags: c#, массивы

```
int[,] array = new int[5, 5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        array[j, i] = i + j;
        Console.WriteLine(array[j, i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот для любых типов можно использовать:

```
public static void PrintMatrix<T>(T[,] matrix)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < matrix.GetLength(0); ++i)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix.GetLength(1); ++j)
    {
      Console.Write($"{matrix[i, j]} ");
      //Console.Write($"{matrix[j, i]} ");
      // Для вывода:
      // H
      // e
      // l
      // l
      // o
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: все равно выводит построчно

Comment: @performance, попробуйте тогда `Console.Write($"{matrix[j, i]} ");`

Answer (score 1):

Написать в самом внутреннем цикле не `WriteLine`, а `Write` видимо

```
 Console.Write(array[j, i]);  // Console.Write(array[j, i] + " "); - для пробела
```

Comment: с числами все верно работает , а со строками так не хочет почему то http://pastebin.com/7iRCRvvz

Comment: А что конкретно означает «не хочет»?

Comment: @performance не знаю вообще что вы пытаетесь творить.....но так-то логично: в строке у вас 20 символов а циклы совершают 25...... Может вы хотели что-то другое спросить и лучше описать конкретно то, что вы пытаетесь решить?)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский объясню конкретно [0,0] = "п" , [1,0] = "р"  , [2,0] = "и" и тд